# Calculating donor retention rate - results artificially lower than expected

Tags: formula, nonprofit-starter-pack

Working to calculate donor retention rate, however the results are lower than when manually calculated. The issue is that if the donated amount from the previous year is greater than the current year, the formula doesn't recognize this individual as being "retained". Is there a way to change up the formula so that this doesn't occur?

Currently, the formula operates off a custom field off the Account Object `Gave_this_year_and_last_year` with the following formula:

```
IF ( npo02__OppsClosedThisYear__c > 0 &&  npo02__OppsClosedLastYear__c > 0, 1, 0)
```

In report builder, I am using the following formula for "Donor Retention Rate"

```
Account.Gave_this_year_and_last_year__c:SUM/RowCount
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For ensuring operator precedence, kindly enclose sub condition with parantheses.

```
IF ( (npo02__OppsClosedThisYear__c > 0) && (npo02__OppsClosedLastYear__c > 0), 1, 0)
```

as operator precedence issue already exists in salesforce formula fields. FYKR - [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160671/operator-precedence-in-formula-field#:~:text=Currently%20(early%202020)%2C%20Salesforce,operators%20are%20evaluated%20before%20exponents](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160671/operator-precedence-in-formula-field#:%7E:text=Currently%20(early%202020)%2C%20Salesforce,operators%20are%20evaluated%20before%20exponents).